# How to compose a filename with multiple string parameters?

Tags: string-manipulation, syntax

Consider some string parameters: `Par1`, `Par2`, `Par3`. Could you please tell me how to compose a filename string of the form:

`filename="experiment-Par1_number-Par2_position-Par3.dat"`

For the data: e.g.,

```
Par1="Exp";
Par2="11";
Par3="End";
```

the filename would be:

```
filename="experiment-Exp_number-11_position-End.dat"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using `StringForm`:**

```
pars = {"Exp", "11", "End"};

fmtString = "experiment-``_number-``_position-``.dat";

filename = ToString@StringForm[fmtString, Sequence @@ pars]
```

> "experiment-Exp_number-11_position-End.dat"

Comment: Note that the result of `StringForm` is not a string and thus not usable as file name for `Import`/`Export` etc. For those cases, you either need to apply `ToString` or use `StringTemplate` instead

Comment: Thanks @LukasLang for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Using `StringJoin`

```
par1 = "Exp";
par2 = "11";
par3 = "End";
filename =  "experiment-" <> par1 <> "_number-" <> par2 <> "_position-" <> par3 <> ".dat"

(* "experiment-Exp_number-11_position-End.dat" *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I actually like StringTemplate for these kinds of things. It's nicely reusable as a function, like a curried StringForm (but it produces actual strings at the end). You also have the option of naming the template slots

```
filenameTemplate = StringTemplate["experiment-``_number-``_position-``.dat"];
filename = filenameTemplate["Exp", 11, "End"]
```

or

```
filenameTemplate = 
  StringTemplate["experiment-`experiment`_number-`number`_position-`position`.dat"];
filename = filenameTemplate[<|"experiment" -> "Exp", "number" -> 11, "position" -> "End"|>]
```

Comment: Without knowing it I have been using a lot of templates for file names but never used `StringTemplate`. This will greatly tidy up my codebase and make things more legible